# Joint distribution of Min max

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

Given:
$$f(x,y) = 2x^2y + \sqrt{y},  \quad 0<x<1, 0<y<1$$
$$U=\min{\{X,Y\}}, V = \max{\{X,Y\}}$$

I am interested in the joint distribution of $U$ and $V$.

Thus:
$$\begin{cases}
U=X \\ 
V=Y
\end{cases}\rightarrow\begin{cases}
X=U \\ 
Y=V
\end{cases}$$

In this case:
$
J_1=\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0& 1
\end{vmatrix}=1
$.

The transformation could also be:
$$\begin{cases}
U=Y \\ 
V=X
\end{cases}\rightarrow\begin{cases}
X=V \\ 
Y=U
\end{cases} $$

In this case:
$
J_2=\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1& 0
\end{vmatrix} =-1
$.

Hence:
$$f(u,v) = (2x^2y + \sqrt{y}) |J_1|  \mathbf{1}_{x=u,y=v}  +  (2x^2y + \sqrt{y}) |J_2|  \mathbf{1}_{x=v,y=u} $$
$$= 2uv(u +  v) + (\sqrt{v}    + \sqrt{u}) $$
Thus:
$$ f(u,v) = 2uv(u +  v) + (\sqrt{v}    + \sqrt{u})  \quad \text{where} \quad 0<u<1, 0<v<1, v>u$$
Is there anyting wrong with this ? is there anyway to simplify the approach

Comment: It is correct. Write the support as $0 \lt u \lt v \lt 1$

Comment: @MathLover Thank you for the feedback